# Prove that some subsets contain two positive integers $ a $ and $ b $ such that $ a|b$

Tags: divisibility

Let $ n $ be a positive integer $(n\ge 2)$ and $ A $ be the set
$$A=\{1,2,3,...,2n\}$$
Prove that

$$(\forall B\subset A)\;$$
$$ \Bigl(\# B=n+1\implies \exists (a,b)\in B^2 \;:\;a\ne b \wedge a|b\Bigr)$$

It is easy to prove it when $ 1\in B $ and when $ 2\in B $ but i have no idea for the other cases.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $b\ne a$ right??

Comment: Two things, isn’t this trivially true since any number will divide itself and do you mean to say that $|B|=n+1$ (cardinality is $n+1$)?

Comment: @QC_QAOA Yes $ a\ne b $ and $\# $ means Cardinality. Thanks.

Comment: For Paul Erdős this was one of his favourite "initiation" questions to mathematics. It is mentioned in the chapter "Pigeon-hole and double counting" in "Proofs from THE BOOK".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B=\{x_1,x_2...x_{n+1}\}\subseteq A$.

Let $x_i=2^{a_i}p_i$ where $2\not|~p_i$ and $a_i\in\Bbb Z_{\ge0}$. Then $p_1,p_2,...,p_{n+1}$ are $n+1$ odd numbers that belong to $S=\{1,3,5,...,2n-1\}$. But $|S|=n$. By the pigeonhole principle, $p_k=p_m$ for some $k\ne m$. This gives $x_k|x_m$ or $x_m|x_k$.

Comment: +1 very nice...

Comment: Thank you very much. God bless you.

Comment: I searched in vain for alternative (less elegant) proofs.  To the best of your knowledge, is there such an alternative proof?

Comment: @user2661923 I can tell you this is a classic pigeonhole problem. But I am not aware of another proof.